# Can't find Android drawable icons

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am trying to create my first android app so I'm messing about with tutorials and in the few I've played with they mention using items from the `drawable` folder but I don't seem to have a `drawable` folder in my `res` folder, only `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi` and `drawable-xxhdpi` and these only contain my project icon.

Is there another location where the `drawable` icons are kept?

Comment: Which icons are you looking for, specifically?

Comment: you can create a drawable folder under res and keep it there in assets or in your own named folder following android folder naming convention

Comment: The tutorial I'm playing with is trying to find `icon_bookmark`, `icon_save`, `icon_search`, `icon_share`, `icon_delete`, `icon_preferences`

Comment: @SaturnsEye link of the tutorial

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/ @Rod_Algonquin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what they want you to do is to create your own drawable, but you can still use the native android drawable by calling:

```
@android:drawable/the_android_drawable
```

where: `the_android_drawable` is the drawable name you can [find here](http://androiddrawables.com/)

**sample:**

```
@android:drawable/ic_menu_account_list
```

`ic_menu_account_list` is located in the menu section of the website link I provided.

Comment: What if the value isn't recognized? For example, I'm getting an error that resource `@android:drawable/ic_cab_done_holo_dark` cannot be resolved.

Comment: @McAdams331 that depends in ur version of android.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder named drawable under res folder and put your drawable in it. and why not use https://code.google.com/p/9patch-resizer/ to automatically resize your images to all resolution compatible for android development?

Answer (score 0):

Just create the drawable folder under res folder, In android you have to follow the static project structure as android use convention over configuration in configuring the resources, strings, menus ..etc.

Please check the android project structure on the following link
http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

but why you don't want to use the android power to enrich your application based on the device screen size for example large(), xlarge ... with the most suitable images, which is better that using drawable only., please check the link below 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create folder name as drawable in res folder